# C#/WPF: Parse many files and show contents in list view

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, parsing, binary

I'm rather new to C#/WPF, so excuse my lack of knowledge/understanding.

I am populating a ListView with data which comes from parsing a fairly large number of binary files (several hundreds if not thousands).

My current approach is to parse all the files in a BackgroundWorker while showing a progress bar (which takes several seconds given the number of files being parsed), read the relevant data from the files into a model list which is bound to the ListView.

This approach doesn't seem ideal to me - particularly the fact that I'm parsing all the files in the beginning when only some of them may be 'active' in the visible ListView area. In other words, it doesn't seem to be making good use of ListView virtualization.

So what's a better approach which makes sense both in terms of efficiency and user experience?

Comment: Try learning MVVM approach. You should seperate View from Model!

Comment: Listview virtualization? in your case I can see only one best approach for each and every file(or say 5 files) create a new thread to read it out ,process it to display in async way for best experience.